# Result saves in two arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm playing around with foreach and Simple HTML dom there I'm trying to save down some links to a array. But my problem is that the result saves in two arrays instead of one array.

```
foreach($html->find('div[class^=voucher success]') as $q)
    {
        @$var = $q->find('a', 0)->href;

        $pos = strpos($var, "/ut/");

        if($pos === false)
        {
            $item[] = $var;
        }

        var_dump($item);
    }
```

Dump:

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(10) "/hm?v=2726" } 
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(10) "/hm?v=2726" [1]=> string(10) "/hm?v=2732" 
}
```

Why is that? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe if you removed the error suppression you would get a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not saving in two arrays. You're dumping the data at the end of every foreach loop. Therefore it dumps twice, because there is two loops in the foreach.

To see the final result of $item you need to dump after the foreach.

```
foreach($html->find('div[class^=voucher success]') as $q)
    {
        @$var = $q->find('a', 0)->href;

        $pos = strpos($var, "/ut/");

        if($pos === false)
        {
            $item[] = $var;
        }
    }

var_dump($item);
```

The output would now be:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(10) "/hm?v=2726" [1]=> string(10) "/hm?v=2732" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is in two arrays? Your var_dump is inside your loop, so it is just dumping each time you iterate.